# The best way to SELECT and if it does not exist, INSERT and SELECT inserted?

Tags: mysql

Let's assume I have a table which contains users' data: there is one column `id` and lots of other columns representing user's data. I want just to take all the data of certain user by his id:

```
SELECT `col1`,`col2`,...,`colN` FROM `users` WHERE `id`=user_id
```

and if a user with such an id does not exist, I want to create him:

```
INSERT INTO `users` SET `id`=user_id, `col1`=col1_std_val, `col2`=col2_std_val...
```

and perform the same SELECT as the first one.

What is the best way to do such an operation?

Wouldn't it be too slow if I create a procedure which does

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `users` SET `id`=user_id, `col1`=col1_std_val, `col2`=col2_std_val...;
SELECT `col1`,`col2`,...,`colN` FROM `users` WHERE `id`=user_id;
```

?

I have this question because games in social networks don't make a request to create a new user but they anticipate that when the user first enters the game, his 'profile' is created automatically.

Comment: How many users are you looking at?

Comment: Why would doing the same operations in the opposite order be slower? The second way is the correct way.

Comment: The speed of queries depends on your configuration. If you use transactions, OS is forcing the hard drive to confirm it wrote the data - that means your performance depends on the speed of your drive. Whether you break things down into procedures that use 2 or 3 different queries - it doesn't really matter that much - lexing will be done rather fast and the time-consuming part is talking to underlying hardware. So to answer your question - the procedure wouldn't be measurably slower or faster than repeating queries one after another. Your bottleneck is not SQL, it's the hardware.

Comment: The reason the second way is correct is that the insert is atomic whether the row is already there or not. If you do it the first way there's a timing window between SELECT and INSERT during which someone else could insert the row.

Comment: @N.B. thanks for the reply, as I understand, it would be fast enough so I shouldn't worry about it.

Comment: @EJP thank you. By doing operations in another order I thought it would be faster because INSERT isn't actually used a lot and this way I would save a lot by not executing it when I don't need. But as I now understand, if the row already exists, INSERT would be fast and so the only thing I need to worry about is making it atomic